# Save "Inspect Element"

Tags: google-chrome

Would anybody know of a way of saving  changes I made in Inspect Element, locally and not server side?

There is some script/plugins for big websites like Facebook that sometimes include a feature where you can change and save the CSS coding you've edited for your own personal viewing. Why isn't there something like this for editing both HTML/CSS and saving for only personal viewing?

Comment: You can use the greasemonkey or tampermonkey extensions to fF and chrome to change the html of a site when it loads.

Comment: Related: [SO: Copying Code from Inspect Element in Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12576247/copying-code-from-inspect-element-in-google-chrome) and [SO: Copying HTML code in Google Chrome's inspect element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23343191/copying-html-code-in-google-chromes-inspect-element)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For HTML

> In "Elements" pane
>
> - Select the root of the document (e.g. )
> - Right click and select "**Copy as HTML**"

For CSS

> In "Sources" pane
>
> - Select modified css file
>
> To review changes:
>
> - Right click and select "Local modifications"
>
> To save changes:
>
> - Right click and select "**Save as...**"

Ref: http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/workflow-tutorials/faster-htmlcss-workflow-with-chrome-developer-tools/

Comment: The link is dead

Comment: @EthanChan The archived link can be found here: https://web.archive.org/web/20220318085534/https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/faster-htmlcss-workflow-with-chrome-developer-tools--webdesign-8314